# Anything like Freemember for EE3?

Tags: redirects, freemember

Or some other means of bypassing the 'thank you, you're logged in' message pages on login/redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something similar with Visitor (https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/visitor) but it's a little more kitchen sink thank Freemember was.